# Homogeneity of regression slopes and collinearly of covariates in ANCOVA (specific)

Tags: spss, assumptions, ancova

Thank you for such a great website for statistics learners, I am currently studying a factorial ANCOVA and have two questions:

1. do we need to test homogeneity of regression slopes for an interaction effect? I feel that the answer is yes, but a bit doubting. What I mean is let's assume I have two independent variables, and if it was a Factorial ANOVA, I would also include an interaction effect to the model, thus there would be 3 effects(2 main and 1 interaction). When we add a covariate, we should test the assumption of homogeneity of regression slopes, we do it for main variables for sure, but what about the interaction effect? Shall we add X1X2Covariate to the model to test if it's significant?
2. When we have several covariates, we usually check for their collinearity in the model, we can enter them into a regular linear regression model and check VIF and tolerance, but if we have a categorical covariate, should we check it too?

Best Regards, Yulia